# iCloud public data possibility

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsdata, icloud

I am developing a iOS/OS X application with a very "nice to have" feature: possibility to sync with non-iCloud clouds.(through web server in example).

The app design already is completely based on iCloud so I was thinking there might be a workaround I could use instead of writing code for one more data marshaling.

Basically what I need is to make some iCloud stored data available to the public OR get user's e-mail/password used for iCloud on iOS/OS X.

The reason why I need it - I'll have to sync data with another cloud and I want to keeps the app lightweight and so move everything to the server (I think I might need OS X server).

Anyways, any suggestion are appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand wanting to do that, but just because you want to do it doesn't mean that you can.

> Basically what I need is to make some iCloud stored data available to the public

I don't believe that there's a way to do that. iCloud isn't a generalized internet hosting service; it's a service designed to make it easy for an *individual* user to share his/her private information among several devices. Creating the possibility of making information public would only undermine the trust that people put in the service.

> OR get user's e-mail/password used for iCloud on iOS/OS X.

That'd put your users in direct violation of the iCloud TOS, which state in part:

> You further acknowledge and agree that the Service is designed and
>   intended for personal use on an individual basis and you should not
>   share your Account and/or password details with another individual.

If you want users to be able to sync their data with other hosting services and you don't want to build that functionality into your mobile app, you might consider building a MacOS X app that the user could run to sync the data.